# Is it possible to log all internal SQL queries in RushORM?

Tags: android, logging, rushorm

I'm using [RushORM](http://www.rushorm.com/) in my project on Android and I feel like it's very difficult to understand. I've been facing issues during my development  which are somehow related to some internal SQL queries RushORM is generating. Unfortunately, RushORM doesn't print any SQL queries in log.

My question: Is it possible to force RushORM to log all SQL queries before sending them to the underlying SQL-engine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced such problems too and found the undocumented solution:
you should simply add

```
<meta-data android:name="Rush_log"
           android:value="true"/>
```

into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to enable it.

You can find more details in a blog post here: http://android-dev.mobi/blog/2015/07/01/rushorm-how-to-enable-debug-logging/